# Proving $Q=\frac{a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}+k\cdot \frac{(ab+bc+ca)}{(a+b+c)^{2}}\geqslant \frac{3}{8}+\frac{k}{3}$

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method, uvw

For $a,b,c\geqslant 0.$ Prove: $$\text{Q}=\frac{a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}+k\cdot \frac{(ab+bc+ca)}{(a+b+c)^{2}}\geqslant \frac{3}{8}+\frac{k}{3},$$
where $k={\frac {27}{8}}+\frac{9\sqrt{3}}{4}$ is a Root Of $64{k}^{2}-432k-243=0.$

By computer (Maple) I found this inequality is equivalent to$:$ $$\sum \Big[ a+b+ ( 1-\frac{\sqrt {3}}{2} ) c\Big]  \Big[ 2(a+b)- ( 1+\sqrt {3} ) c \Big] ^{2} ( \,a-b \,) ^{2} \geqslant 0$$

But I hope for alternative proof$?$

Comment: Did you try pqr method?

Comment: @RiverLi Since the inequality have more than one equality case, I don't think pqr method help here. But I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, our inequality it's a linear inequality of $w^3$, which says that it's enough to prove our inequality for an extreme value of $w^3$, which by $uvw$ happens in the following  cases.

1. $w^3=0$.

Let $c=0$, $b=1$ and $a^2+1=2ua$.

Thus, $u\geq1$ and we need to prove here that
$$\frac{a^2-a+1}{a}+\frac{ka}{(a+1)^2}\geq\frac{3}{8}+\frac{k}{3}$$ or
$$2u-1+\frac{k}{2u+2}\geq\frac{3}{8}+\frac{k}{3}$$ or
$$4u^2-\left(\frac{2k}{3}-\frac{5}{4}\right)u+\frac{k}{3}-\frac{5}{4}\geq0,$$ for which it's enough to prove that
$$\left(\frac{2k}{3}-\frac{5}{4}\right)^2-16\left(\frac{k}{3}-\frac{5}{4}\right)\leq0,$$ which is true for $k=\frac{27}{8}+\frac{9\sqrt{3}}{4}.$

2. Two variables are equal.

Let $b=c=1$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$\frac{a^3+2}{2(a+1)^2}+\frac{k(2a+1)}{(a+2)^2}\geq\frac{3}{8}+\frac{k}{3}$$
or
$$\frac{4a^3-3a^2-6a+5}{8(a+1)^2}\geq\frac{k(a-1)^2}{3(a+2)^2}$$ or
$$(4a+5)(a+2)^2\geq(9+6\sqrt3)(a+1)^2$$ or
$$(2a+4-\sqrt3)(2a+1-\sqrt3)^2\geq0$$ and we are done!

Answer (score 1):

*Another way*

Let $p = a + b + c = 3, q = ab+bc+ca, r = abc$.

Since $(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2 \ge 0$ that is $-4p^3r+p^2q^2+18pqr-4q^3-27r^2 \ge 0$,
we have
\begin{align}
r &\ge -\frac{2}{27}p^3 + \frac{1}{3}pq - \frac{2}{27}\sqrt{(p^2 - 3q)^3}\\
&= q - 2 - 2\sqrt{(1-q/3)^3}.\tag{1}
\end{align}

We have to prove that
$$\frac{p^3 - 3pq + 3r}{pq - r} - \frac{3}{8} \ge k\left(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{q}{p^2}\right).$$
From (1), it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{p^3 - 3pq + 3(q - 2 - 2\sqrt{(1-q/3)^3})}{pq - (q - 2 - 2\sqrt{(1-q/3)^3})} - \frac{3}{8} \ge k\left(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{q}{p^2}\right)$$
or
$$\frac{27(1-q/3)(3 - \sqrt{1-q/3})}{8q + 8 + 8\sqrt{(1-q/3)^3}}\ge \frac{k}{3}(1 - q/3).$$
It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{81(3 - \sqrt{1-q/3})}{8q + 8 + 8\sqrt{(1-q/3)^3}}\ge k.$$
With the substitution $q = 3 - \frac{t^2}{3}$ for $0 \le t \le 3$, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{729(9-t)}{8(t+3)(6-t)^2} \ge k.$$
It is easy to prove that
$$\frac{729(9-t)}{8(t+3)(6-t)^2} - \frac{27}{8}
= \frac{27t^2(9 - t) + 27^2(5 - t)}{8(t+3)(6-t)^2}
> 0$$
and
$$\left(\frac{729(9-t)}{8(t+3)(6-t)^2} - \frac{27}{8}\right)^2 - \frac{243}{16}
= \frac{243(99-6t-t^2)(t^2 - 12t + 9)^2}{64(t+3)^2(6-t)^4} \ge 0$$
which results in
$$\frac{729(9-t)}{8(t+3)(6-t)^2} \ge \frac{27}{8} + \frac{9\sqrt{3}}{4}.$$
(Alternatively, we may use derivatives to find the minimum of $\frac{729(9-t)}{8(t+3)(6-t)^2}$ on $[0, 3]$.)

We are done.

Comment: +1) Thanks. $k={\frac {27}{8}}+\frac{9\sqrt{3}}{4}$ is also the best constant here!

Comment: @tthnew Yes. In this problem, the best constant has a closed form.

Comment: So, from your proof, this inequality can be also prove by https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1101515h2255918_helpful_lemma_for_the_homogeneous_inequality

Comment: @tthnew Similarly, we have the following: Lemma 1: Let $a, b, c > 0; \ a+b+c = 1; \ ab+bc+ca = \frac{1}{3+t^2}\ $ ($t\ge 0$). Then
$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} \ge (t+1)^2+\frac{2}{t+1}.$$

Comment: Yes, also $\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a} \ge \dfrac{2(27q^2-9q+1)}{9q^2-2q+(1-3q)\sqrt{q(1-3q)}}+\dfrac{1}{q}-6,$ 

where $p =a+b+c=1,q=ab+bc+ca$

Comment: @tthnew The same. Often we need to eliminate root signs. If the inequality has the form of $\sqrt{X} + \sqrt{Y} + \sqrt{Z} \ge \sqrt{U} + \sqrt{V} + \sqrt{W}$, often it is difficult to eliminate the root signs.

Comment: Yes, sometimes we need to use some other inequality to eliminate the sqrt.

Comment: For homogeneous inequality, by letting $a+b+c=1$ and $ab+bc+ca = \frac{1}{3+t^2}$, sometimes we can transform the inequality to the one of single variable. Another example, Let $a, b, c > 0; \ a+b+c = 1; \ ab+bc+ca = \frac{1}{3+t^2}\ $ ($t\ge 0$). I think that 
$$\frac{a^2}{b} + \frac{b^2}{c} + \frac{c^2}{a} \ge
t^2-\frac{1}{t^2+3} + \frac{2(t^6+4t^4+4t^2+4)}{t^3(t^2+3)\sqrt{t^2+3}+2(t^2+3)}.$$

Comment: @tthnew $$a^2/b+b^2/c+c^2/a-t^2+1/(t^2+3)-(2*(t^6+4*t^4+4*t^2+4))/(t(t^2+3)^3*sqrt(t^2+3)+2*(t^2+3))$$

Comment: $t(t^2+3)^3$ or $t^3(t^2+3)$?

Comment: @tthnew $t^3(t^2+3)$

Comment: It's hard. Bottema2009 can't not check, it lead to very high degree.

Comment: @tthnew Thank you for checking.